# 'ng build --prod' fails with template compile error

Tags: angular

```
ERROR in Error during template compile of 'BootstrapSwitchComponent'  
Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'trigger' was called.
```

Comment: can you please update your question with the complete log details.

Comment: looks like you have used a method which is never used in `BootstrapSwitchComponent` component

Comment: Thanks for helping, Once I execute ng build --prod it compiles the code, but at the time of compilation completion it shows above message and quit. When execute without --prod it works. Below mentioned answer works for me, but I couldn't reason out why its executing.